# Drilldown on category group for stacked chart - ssrs 2008?

Tags: reporting-services, drilldown

Is it possible to include drill down or link to report functionality in the category group (x-axis) for a stacked bar chart report?

Comment: Do you mean the clicking on the axis itself or the different value areas in the actual chart area?

Comment: The values that are listed on the x-axis e.g. To click on Q1-2012 and drill into Jan-Mar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, based on the comments above it's not exactly possible to do what you're asking. You can certainly apply drillthrough actions at a **data** level, which would mean users could click on the chart area:

[image]

So you would to set the Action up to pass a parameter based the series/category of the area thats clicked, which would effectively accomplish the same result, just in a slightly different way. But clicking directly on the axis is not possible.

Comment: In my scenario, I already have a drill down on the data level which links to another report but I was hoping to be able to drill into the timeline listed on the x-axis. I searched the web and couldn't find anything of the sort but now you've confirmed my suspicion. Cheers.